# Does Julia have support for audio processing

Tags: julia, audio-processing

I want to play around with audio at low level. I want functionality such as reading mp3 files and creating audio files (with both channels independently controllable). The ability to listen to generated audio in the code notebook (I am using Pluto) on the fly would be much appreciated. Are there any packages that allow one to achieve this? I found this: https://github.com/JuliaAudio/MP3.jl/ but it doesn't seem to be maintained and upon trying to install it I run into an error saying 'no project file' which seems to a new requirement for julia packages that was added recently.

I am completely new to Julia and have python and javascript experience. Decided to do this project in Julia instead of python just to pick up this language.

Comment: There is also [MusicProcessing.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMusic/MusicProcessing.jl). It is definitely less feature-rich than the options in Python, but it is being actively developed and looks like it may one day become the de-facto audio processing library in Julia.

Comment: Also, if you aren't wedded to mp3 (ie if you're willing to convert your source file to something else first) then there are other options too, see eg [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/audio-processing-in-julia/35248)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there are 2 forks with julia 1 support

- https://github.com/wherrera10/MP3.jl
- https://github.com/dms449/MP3.jl

I have no idea if they work and if they are maintained

Comment: The first one works. takes forever to load the mp3 file and for a while I thought my computer was done for, but works. Automatically creates a player in the notebook which works. Now I have to figure out how to manipulate the object it returns.

Comment: @point.blank_ Given you are new to Julia be aware the long run-time on initial load could be compile-time. That is, the second time you try to load a file in the same session may be much, much faster.

Comment: Okay, so it's not a compile time thing that the computer freezes up. Alteast the computer does get back to normal functioning with no problems after the read finishes and I don't have to force restart. But I think I should leave this question as unanswered as I have decided to use python for atleast converting the mp3 to wav files which will hopefully load better.